# How to use backdrop-filter in Electron?

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I'm currently trying to use a backdrop-filter in electron.js, to create a blur-behind effect that'll work over dynamic elements, instead of just over a single background image.

As it is not currently supported in stable chrome, I'm using as as an experimental feature, as mentioned in extreme brief [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/backdrop-filter-compatibility-in-electron/33280/3). He does mention not "prefixing" the CSS rule, but does not mention to what or provide any other context, so I am unclear what he is saying.

I'm creating my electron window with:

```
function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      experimentalFeatures: true
    }
  })
}
```

Which, as I understand it, should enable experimental features. And then attempting to use it inside a vue component with the simple CSS rule:

```
<style scoped>
  .blurred-box{
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
</style>
```

Which currently does nothing, at all. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Is this still possible in the modern versions of electron? Is this possible by some alternative experimental blink feature, if not?

I'll admit some degree of concern it may be deprecated, as I cannot get other demos from github running, either, it appears.

Comment: first of all, what version of Electron are you on. Second, is that page loaded directly into that BrowserWindow, or is there also a webview in between

Comment: There shouldnt be a webview in between, this is a SPA. I am using Vue.JS components, but as they're all being loaded into the same view I cant imagine they dont have access to the same options?

As for electron version, I'm on version 4.

Comment: Can you see that style on your element in devtools? (Is the style correctly scoped...)

Comment: It appears to see that it exists, yeah: https://i.imgur.com/t9DqDCp.jpg . It's just not actually... displaying anything.

Comment: the prefixing refers to the the `webkit-` prefix. He says not to use that (which you're not). Based on the image, the style is being applied. Is there a chance that you're misunderstanding what it does? From looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) one of the elements or the background needs to be transparent. Is that the case?

Comment: fwiw, they're [planning](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/GRl1_Qy97jM/h7v1qIDsBwAJ) on shipping this feature soon (my understanding is that it's already available behind the experimental features flag, but soon it will be the default), so when Electron takes the next Chromium version, maybe you'll see it then... otherwise not sure

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what it does. The situation it is in, right now, is a transparent <div> placed over a <img>, and I'm hoping the div will blur the image. Will it only blur a CSS background property, and not dynamically?

Comment: Sounds like you're using it correctly. Does it work in the browser (outside of Electron)?

Comment: That was an excellent suggestion. For whatever reason, it didn't until I stuck relative positioning on it. Then it works file. No idea why, but tacking a relative positioning on the element appears to have totally resolved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: oh that div probably wasn't over what you wanted.